# Can't Toggle VPN to "On" Position

Tags: vpn, openvpn

In my Network Settings GUI, when I try to toggle the VPN to "on", it briefly switches to the on position then immediately goes to off. In other words, it won't let me turn the VPN on.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Yu

Comment: Ensure that the VPN server is working properly, and that you actually have a reliable network connection..

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue in Ubuntu 18.04 and resolved it by navigating to the identity tab of the vpn settings, clicking on the password settings and changing the setting from "Store the password only for this user" to "Store the password for all users".

Comment: That's it! It's a little icon on the right of the password field.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue once I installed the **network-manager** for **openvpn-gnome**. The issue was resolved after I restarted the computer.
I had Ubuntu 18.04 installed in my laptop.